# Conversões de JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

Sou iniciante em C# e ASP.NET, e estou com dúvidas a respeito de JSON e dicionários

Possuo um dictionary serializado que foi armazenado no banco de dados com:

```
var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
.Serialize(filtros.ToDictionary(item => item.Key.ToString(),
                                item =>     item.Value.ToString()));
```

Após serializado este dictionary ele é armazenadas no banco de dados, pois estás informações utilizarei depois em uma exibição (PopUp em asp.net).

A minha dificuldade está em deserializar estes valores que estão no banco de dados para colocá-los novamente em um dictionary. Tentei:

Código que usou para recuparar as informações no banco de dados:

```
<asp:Literal ID="lblFiltros" runat="server" 
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FiltroJson")%> ' />
```

A unica forma que conseguir coletar as informações no code behind foi:

```
object filtros = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
.DeserializeObject(((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lblFiltros")).Text);
```

Entretanto, não consigo utilizá-lo com iterações e nem mesmo é uma Dictionary. Com Dictionary utilizei o seguinte trecho de código:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> filtros = new 
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Ou seja, quando preciso `.Add` a `chave` e o `valor` na minha Dictionary não só tenho uma grande string que é o valor que recebo no `Literal`:

```
 ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lblFiltros")).Text
```

Como posso fazer está conversão da forma correta? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido:

Utilizei a framework Json.NET aplicada pelo Nugget no Visual Studio 2015 e a importei no projeto:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Recebi os valores do .aspx:

```
string serializada = @"" + ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lblFiltros")).Text
```

E para deserializar utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
Dictionary<string, string> valores = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(serializada);
```

Obs.: o método `JsonConvert` pertence ao pacote importado.